# Squid not delivering the cached content

Tags: caching, proxy, squid

I'm trying to build the content cache server with squid.

I confirmed that the squid is caching and forwarding the contents correctly.
However, squid doesn't reuse cached contents for other requests with same URL.

I've searched the logs and found some that looks like the reason.
Please help me to fix this issue.

**X-Ws-Request-Id header changed and No Content-Length header on response**

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 00:34:33 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Connection: close
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Allow: GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD
> X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
> Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date, Server, Content-Type, Content-Length
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> Via: 1.1 PShgseSEL4mz119:15 (W)
> X-Px: ms PShgseSEL4mz119GMP(origin)
> X-Ws-Request-Id: 61edf419_PShgseSEL4mz119_197044-1706
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, User-Agent, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range, x-datadog-origin, x-datadog-parent-id, x-datadog-sampled, x-datadog-sampling-priority, x-datadog-trace-id
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Cache-Control: max-age=86400

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Mon, 24 Jan 2022 00:41:14 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Connection: close
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Allow: GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD
> X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
> Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date, Server, Content-Type, Content-Length
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> Via: 1.1 PShgseSEL4mz119:15 (W)
> X-Px: ms PShgseSEL4mz119GMP(origin)
> X-Ws-Request-Id: 61edf5aa_PShgseSEL4mz119_193496-22946
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, User-Agent, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range, x-datadog-origin, x-datadog-parent-id, x-datadog-sampled, x-datadog-sampling-priority, x-datadog-trace-id
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Cache-Control: max-age=86400

**cache.log**

> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 11,3| http.cc(920) haveParsedReplyHeaders: HTTP CODE: 200
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 73,3| HttpRequest.cc(687) storeId: sent back canonicalUrl:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 20,3| store_dir.cc(1073) get: storeGet: looking up 23FD8DC4DB74AAABF696B3AD8F4857E4
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 20,4| store_dir.cc(744) find: none of 1 cache_dirs have 23FD8DC4DB74AAABF696B3AD8F4857E4
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 73,3| HttpRequest.cc(687) storeId: sent back canonicalUrl:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 20,3| store_dir.cc(1073) get: storeGet: looking up 802B4D5585C2B67E0329F5B8C323E6CF
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 20,4| store_dir.cc(744) find: none of 1 cache_dirs have 802B4D5585C2B67E0329F5B8C323E6CF
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 22,3| http.cc(330) cacheableReply: NO because e:=p2XDIV/0x558f4b4052e0*3 has been released.
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| 20,3| store.cc(813) expireNow: StoreEntry::expireNow: '3EA6671585FCE64FF9973D39362A24EB'
> 2022/01/23 19:41:22.160 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
> ....
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,3| store.cc(1052) complete: storeComplete: '3EA6671585FCE64FF9973D39362A24EB'
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,3| store.cc(1347) validLength: storeEntryValidLength: Checking '3EA6671585FCE64FF9973D39362A24EB'
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,5| store.cc(1349) validLength: storeEntryValidLength:     object_len = 890
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,5| store.cc(1350) validLength: storeEntryValidLength:         hdr_sz = 890
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,5| store.cc(1351) validLength: storeEntryValidLength: content_length = -1
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,5| store.cc(1354) validLength: storeEntryValidLength: Unspecified content length: 3EA6671585FCE64FF9973D39362A24EB
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,3| store_swapout.cc(356) mayStartSwapOut:  already rejected
> 2022/01/23 19:41:24.207 kid1| 20,2| store.cc(953) checkCachable: StoreEntry::checkCachable: NO: not cachable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.